# Filtering using WHERE for a subquery

Tags: mysql

i consider myself a pretty well-versed developer, but this one has me stumped.

The actual use case is somewhat more complicated than this (i have built a data-view framework that allows you to filter and search data), but at its simplest...

Why can't I do something like this?:

```
SELECT
    fundraisers.id,
    (
        SELECT
            count(*)
        FROM
            transactions
        WHERE
            transactions.fundraiser_id = fundraisers.id) AS total
    FROM
        fundraisers
    WHERE
        total > 331
    ORDER BY
        total DESC
```

I've also tried:

- I'm aware i can successfully use `HAVING` to do this, but i need it to be part of the WHERE clause in order to be able to use it in conjunction with other filters using the right AND/OR conditions.
- doing it as a subquery JOIN instead, but it never seems to return the right count of transactions for the row.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks folks.

Comment: *Why can't I do something like this?* Because the output alias cannot be used in WHERE - according value does not exists when WHERE is processed.

Comment: *I'm aware i can successfully use HAVING to do this, but i need it to be part of the WHERE clause in order to be able to use it in conjunction with other filters using the right AND/OR conditions.* https://xyproblem.info/

Comment: please describe what your query is attempting in english too?

Comment: Essentially i'm trying to say "show me every row from FUNDRAISERS and include a column that is the number of transactions that have the `fundraiser_id` that matches the one in the row. But only show me fundraisers that have more than 331 transactions".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a derived table, in other words a subquery in the FROM clause instead of the select-list.

```
SELECT t.fundraiser_id, t.total
FROM
    fundraisers AS f
JOIN (
    SELECT fundraiser_id, COUNT(*) AS total
    FROM transactions
    GROUP BY fundraiser_id
) AS t ON t.fundraiser_id = f.id
WHERE
    t.total > 331
ORDER BY
    t.total DESC;
```

The reason you can't refer to an alias in the WHERE clause is that the conditions of the WHERE clause is evaluated before expressions in the select-list are evaluated. This is a good thing, because you wouldn't want the select-list to be evaluated for potentially millions of rows that would be filtered out by the conditions anyway. Evaluating the select-list only for rows that are included in the result helps improve performance.

But it means the result of those expressions in the select-list, and their alias, isn't available to be referenced by conditions in the WHERE clause.

The workaround I show in my example above produces the results in a subquery, which happens before the WHERE clause gets to filter the results.

Comment: Thanks Bill, I could have sworn i tried this and it didn't work - hundreds of the rows were returning `1` and then groups of rows would return larger counts than that, i'm assuming it's cause of something i got wrong with the `ON` condition - i'll try and compare this to what i'd done already and figure it out. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

i don't know what do you want to select but try this

```
select fundraisers.id,count(*) as total FROM
        fundraisers f join transactions t on t.fundraiser_id=f.fundraiser_id
    WHERE
        total > 331
    ORDER BY
        total DESC
```

Comment: The problem with this is that it'll return a row for every transaction that matches the fundraiser - i need to keep it to one row per fundraiser and aggregate.